# Php script query on mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So I used php to connect my android app to a mysql database. I tested both the app and the queries on several small databases. Everything worked fine. 
Using the old query on a larger database made the php query load forever in the web browser thus not displaying the intended JSON. So I made a new query but it doesn't display any result in the app, plus, it only displays the last result on the query. Is there any way for this to work out correctly?

Old php query that works on small db, but loads forever in the web browser with larger db:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

$response = array();

require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT eid,marca,investimento,marcatotal,dataconstituicao,datainicio FROM empresa") or die(mysql_error());

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response["empresa"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $product = array();
        $product["eid"] = $row["eid"];
        $product["marca"] = $row["marca"];
        $product["investimento"] = $row["investimento"];
        $product["dataconstituicao"] = $row["dataconstituicao"];
        $product["datainicio"] = $row["datainicio"];

        array_push($response["empresa"], $product);
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;

    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No empresa found";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

New php query that I created that displays ONLY the last result in web browser and doesn't show anything in the app on new larger db:

```
<?php

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(0);

require_once('db_config.php');

$conn = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_password) or die(mysql_error());

$db=  mysql_select_db($db_database, $conn);

$sql="SELECT eid,marca,investimento,marcatotal,dataconstituicao,datainicio FROM empresa" ;

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');

$rs = mysql_query($sql,$conn);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))

{
    $i=0;
    foreach($row as $key => $value)   
    {
        if (is_string($key))
        {
         $fields[mysql_field_name($rs,$i++)] = $value;
        }  
    }
    $json_result ["empresa"] =  $fields;
}

$response = json_encode($json_result);

print_r($response);

?>
```

Comment: The mysql_query extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Is that a reason for the query to not work?

Comment: The reason why you're only getting the last row is because you're overwriting the value of `$json_result ["empresa"]` each time through the loop. You probably want something like `$json_result ["empresa"][] =  $fields;`

Comment: To re-iterate, [**don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: That is exactly the response to my specific question. Unfortunately my app that used to display all the results now doesn't show anything in my list, even though it used to in my old query.. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your app may be expecting/requiring the `success` field in the result, which was present in your old code, but is not in the new code. I would try adding that logic back and see what happens.

Comment: You are also correct.  It has been a long time since I picked up this app and I don't remember a lot about my own app. It is expecting the success=1. However, I have tried it and I don't exactly know how to put the "$response["success"] = 1;" in my php query. Any suggestion?

Comment: You're using "die(mysql_error());". If you're not getting any error, then the problem isn't in the MySQL query. If it's taking too much time to load, then you're probably selecting a huge dataset from the database. Use MySQL `LIMIT` to get a smaller dataset.

Comment: Using the second php query I can get all the data displayed in the browser instantly ( less than 1 sec ). In the first query, which supposedly does the same thing, it just loads forever. I waited 1 hour and doesn't display anything.. ( around 1200 results, from eid 600 to eid 1800 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aswer from Patrick Q is correct:
$json_result ["empresa"] had to be $json_result ["empresa"][] = $fields;
Also, his suggestion helped me solve my problem further since I just removed the success=1 logic alltogether from my app in order for it to work. Thank you all for the help!